# Printing pascal's triangle in C

Tags: c

I have to print the pascal's triangle given a certain number of levels desired. The max levels that will be asked for is 28. I am able to print the some of the rows correctly but then it starts printing negative numbers in the rest of my rows. I can't figure out why, help would be much appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void printTriangle() {
  int numLevels;
  printf("Please enter how many levels of Pascal's Triangle you would like to see: ");
  scanf("%d", &numLevels);

  char pascalTriangle[28][28];

  for (int k = 1; k <= numLevels; ++k) {
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
      int val = (i == 0) || (i == k - 1) ? 1 : (pascalTriangle[k-1][i-1] + pascalTriangle[k-1][i]);
      pascalTriangle[k][i] = val;
      printf(" %d", val);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  printTriangle();
}
```

Comment: Where exactly does it start printing negative numbers? Can you show an example that doesn't depend on user input?

Comment: I don't recall the rate of growth for Pascal's triangle, but I do notice that your 2d-array is of type `char` and you're assigning `val` to it, which is an `int`.  I assume you're overflowing that `char`.

Comment: If you enable full warnings you'll probably get a warning about the assignment to `pascalTriangle[k][i]`

Comment: Okay, having run the code, it looks like it is your char is definitely overflowing.  Also you've got an off-by-1 error since you're looping starting at 1, so you're going to go past the end of your array on the final loop.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it starts printing negative at line 12

Comment: Change `char pascalTriangle[28][28];` to `long long pascalTriangle[28][28];`. You're going over the max `char` value so it goes to negative. Also, change `k <= numLevels` to `k < numLevels`. This prevents the segmentation fault.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons okay so what should I do to fix the char overflowing?

Comment: @Dock I am not allowed to use long long in my code. Only arrays and integers.

Comment: @TylerBeckler a `long long` is an integer but bigger. There is no "array" type, only a collection of pointers.  You can also change `char` to `int`, `short`, `long`, etc.

Comment: `int` will fit the numbers just fine assuming a 32-bit int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `char pascalTriangle[28][28];` to `int pascalTriangle[28][28];`. You're going over the max `char` value so it goes to negative.

There is no "array" type, only a collection of pointers.  You can also change `char` to `short`, `long`, etc.

Also, change `k <= numLevels` to `k < numLevels`. This prevents the segmentation fault. To fix the logic, you have to change `for(int i = 0;` to `for(int i = -1`;

The fixed code is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void printTriangle() {
  int numLevels;
  printf("Please enter how many levels of Pascal's Triangle you would like to see: ");
  scanf("%d", &numLevels);

  long long pascalTriangle[28][28];

  for (int k = 0; k < numLevels; ++k) {
    for (int i = -1; i < k; ++i) {
      long long val = (i == 0) || (i == k - 1) ? 1 : (pascalTriangle[k-1][i-1] + pascalTriangle[k-1][i]);
      pascalTriangle[k][i] = val;
      printf(" %lld", val);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  printTriangle();
}
```

Comment: You will want to also check the return value of `scanf`, and also, starting `i` at -1 will cause problems on the first iteration.